# Logging for Locks in MySQL

Tags: mysql, logging, innodb, locks

How do i enable logs for locks in MySQL? For example, if i run **select * from table** on my InnoDB table, MySQL must internally lock this table.

I want to learn how and when MySQL locks my table and in what modes. A log would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to clarify that `SELECT * FROM table` will not set locks with your InnoDB table.  Please see my answer here:

[Confusion regarding INNODB locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218588/confusion-regarding-innodb-locking/23224643#23224643)

Regarding a log for locks:

It is likely the case that this would generate far too much information, and reduce throughput for high traffic database servers.

You may be interested in checking out `performance_schema` which is a set of internal meta data tables inside of MySQL that can be queried to show lock wait information.