# Confusion regarding INNODB locking

Tags: mysql, innodb, locks

When i run 'Select * from table' on an INNODB table, does the table get locked implicity? Does it mean that during the time MySQL takes to return the result set, i cannot issue an update statement on the table?

From what i have understood, the whole table would be locked in shared mode until the result set is returned from the server. Only then could the update command be executed.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Haven't tried. Just asking for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: Have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB uses a feature called [Multi-version concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).

Locking in shared mode is not required, since `MVCC` will retain earlier versions of the row for your `SELECT` statement to be able to read if required.

So the answer is 'no', running a `SELECT` statement will not need to lock any rows while updating.  That is, unless it is a special `SELECT` statement like `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`.